# Cycles compute device for rendering is GPU but actually CPU get's used

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I'm trying to render with gpu in cycles render but, even tho looking at the settings it seems like everything should be fine , actually looking at cpu and gpu usage i noticed that the one actually being used for rendering was still the cpu.

[image: here's a screen of my settings:]

my cpu model is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3550 CPU @ 3.30GHz

my gpu model is GeForce GTX 1080

my CUDA version is 8.0.61

can someone help me figure out why is this happening? 
thank you :)

Comment: Your CPU is used while rendering with GPU, however it shouldn't be by a large number. Could you provide a screenshot of your CPU/GPU usage?

Comment: right now i can't but i remember clearly that every time cpu usage would be 100% while gpu around 3-7%.. so my best guess is blender is not using it at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved it.. in the end looks like there were some leftovers from older versions of the nvidia drivers that were causing conflict because i wiped clean the pc and reinstalled the drivers and now gpu rendering works as it should.